# Security in web sockets

Tags: web-application, penetration-test, websocket

Scope: penetration testing of web server with critical information in it (user management).

I had an argument with my college about security in web sockets and I got stuck with him in one topic, which is the following:

- Is it secure to let any inbound connection into the web-socket
  without filtering the source of the connection?

Let me explain my opinion on that:

- **Only an authorized user** (by a certain cookie which is on the server already)  can  connect to the web-sockets gateway (WSG) via
  server S, then happens the handshake, 101, and the communication
  starts.

His opinion is that:

- Every user, no matter whether it has the cookie or not, can query the
  web-socket gatewa y.

From my point of view, if we allow  any connection request to the web-socket gateway, it may result into:

1. Unrestricted flood.
2. Scans.
3. Exploitation of possible vulnerability of the server to extract sensitive data.

What do you think?

Comment: I'm not sure if I get the full context: I hope that both you and your college agree that sensitive data should only be provided to authorized (and thus authenticated) users. You explain how you think the authentication should be done but you don't explain how your college thinks it should be done - you seem to imply that he does not authenticate anything (which I doubt). Since I don't have the necessary information about both approaches I cannot compare these approaches.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich however indeed sensitive data should be accessed thought authentication  but as he stated he doesn't see any security issue in having the socket open to any connection from outside. (meaning that for exaple i can ping the socket by sending some crafted JSON it is open to the internet and doesn't return 502 or 403  )
 it sounds really wired to me since I find it insecure.

Comment: The webserver is also open to the internet in your own proposal. Please explain what you see as the difference between having the webserver open to the internet and having the websocket server open as long as no access to sensitive data is possible without authorization? All the attack scenarios you describe are true for the webserver too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Websockets are not inherently less secure then "normal" web traffic. What you describe as possible attacks against the websocket server can also be used as attacks against your websockets gateway. And while you can check an authentication cookie early in the webserver and abandon the request if necessary you could also check some authentication information early in the websockets connection and quickly close the websocket if needed.

Still, if you already have a webserver which acts both as gateway or server for the web application and for the server and which has already implemented checks for authentication it makes sense to use the same authentication for both web application and websockets instead of implementing  another one specific to the websockets backend.